# JsonRestStore: get all objects with POST + Body instead of GET

Tags: javascript, rest, dojo

I use dojo to connect my frontend grid via JsonRestStore to my backend api. At the moment I instantiate my store with

```
    require(["dojo/store/JsonRest"], function (JsonRest) {
        myStore = new JsonRest({ target: 'https://myapi.com', handleAs: 'json'
        });
    });
```

As I see the store performs a GET Request to get all objects of my REST api. So what if I need to perform a non-REST-conform request with a POST request and body content to get all objects (instead of GET). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without overriding any functionality? I'm almost sure that it can't be done. As the [API Documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dojo/store/JsonRest) itself says, it's performing a `GET` request when calling the `query()` function.

So to implement this behavior by yourself you will probably have to override the `query()` functionality and maybe also the `getChildren()`, `getMetadata()` and `getIdentity()` functions (I'm not sure if they call the REST API or not).

It's only common sense that this cannot be changed since your request isn't (conform) REST (like you said), but we're talking about a RESTful webservice-based store.